# How to change the name that appears on the top of android studio window?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I have created a project with the name: "ToDeleteImmediately".
Later i regret and wanted to work with this project, so i decided to change it's name to "AllScoresScreen".
I have made the following changes:
1.Renamed the folder name from com.example.ToDeleteImmediately  to com.example.allScoresScreen.
2.Renamged the package name
3.Renamed the app name in Manifest.xml
4.In Explorer also changed the folder name
But i still see the old name in the Android studio
Please see the attached pic.
Maybe someone can tell me what can i do because it's really bothering me.

[image]

Comment: Check in `settings.gradle` to see if it has a reference to the old name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recent versions of Android Studio have been putting a display name for the project in `settings.gradle` as `rootProject.name`:

```
include ':app'
rootProject.name = "My Application"
```

That value is not essential, so you can remove it or change it to a new value as you see fit.

Comment: i have just noticed that the R file path is still contain the old name. Maybe you can guess how can i change it too?

Comment: @Eitanos30: I am not completely certain what you mean. AFAIK, in Android Studio 4.0+, `R` is not generated as source anymore. Can you provide more details and an example?

Comment: when i use the follwoing code:*        val countryNameTextView : TextView?  = view.findViewById(R.id.country_name_tv)
*, the correspsonding import is: import **com.example.todeleteimmediatley.R**
 and not **com.example.newName.R**

Comment: @Eitanos30: That comes from your `package` attribute in your `<manifest>` element in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough to rename the top project folder on file system, then reopen project

Comment: thanks but in order to fix it i had to do what CommonsWare suggested me